# Upgrading to PostSharp 5 essentials, I am now getting a License error

Tags: postsharp

I get the following error after upgrading to PostSharp 5.0.41.

Error   286 License error. The project uses non-licensed features. It is not allowed to enhance or analyze more than 10 classes in each project by features not covered by the installed licenses. Please visit https://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp.

I am using the essentials license and PostSharp.Aspects.

Thank you

Comment: From which version were you upgrading?

Comment: Looking at previous threads on this - it is clarified that there should not be more than 10 target classes using this on the essentials license for version 5.  Does that mean 10 classes overall in the project or 10 classes using the PostSharp.Aspects library as we only have 9 classes in our entire solution that use PostSharp.Aspects.

Comment: upgrading from 4.2.28

Answer (score 2):

The licensing of PostSharp 5 Essentials is no longer backward compatible with PostSharp 4.2 Express. See http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-50-RTM (look for "Changes in the Product Line and Licensing") for details.